# add external style sheet in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, external

I am using Rails 3.2.1. How do I add external style sheets in my rails application?

I've tried the following answers to no avail:

- [How do I link to an external stylesheet in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947218/) - but the link given in the answer is not working.
- [How do I use CSS with a ruby on rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804961/) - which says to add stylesheet in public/stylesheets, but I do not have folder named `public/stylesheets`. I do have a public folder, but I have stylesheets folder under `/vendor/assets`.
- [css @import external style sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347178/) - but it's unclear.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about why `stylesheet_link_tag` isn't working for you?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Off course it is. I have given link to the same in my question, but the answer for that question is not working. I hope it is valid reason to post the question again, and does not deserve a sownvote.

Comment: @James: Well, I have not tried stylesheet_link_tag because I have not added the stylesheets yet because I do not know exactly where i am supposed to put stylesheet files.

Comment: The word external is throwing people off I think, you just want to import .css files right? Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9138946/859762

Comment: It's a dupe if the question is the same, not the answer. Can't speak to the downvote, it wasn't mine.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Ok, I agree its a dupe, but,the answer in the original question is not working, also, I did not receive any response when I pointed out that the answer is not working. So, now, my question is what am I supposed to do in this case.

Comment: The correct thing to have done in this situation would have been to post a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) on the original question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm just going to assume you're already using something like this in your layout:

`stylesheet_link_tag 'application'`

If you want to refer to an external stylesheet then all you need to do is pass in the url.

`stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.1/build/reset/reset-min.css'`

If you want to include the actual files in your codebase:

`app/assets/stylesheets` is where you should place your main css files.

`vendor/assets/stylesheets` is where you should place the css files for any plugins that you might have.

It's the same for js files. For example your `application.js` would go in `app/assets/javascripts` and a jquery plugin like `timeago.js` would go in `vendor/assets/javascripts`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually my question was "at what path" in my application directory should I put my js and css files? Later I can use stylesheet_link_tag.

Comment: Phew...now its much more clear...thanks a lot. One last thing, do we need to put plugins in "vendor"? If yes why? If no..what is advantage/reason for putting my plugins into vendor directory

Comment: There isn't an actual requirement for putting plugins into the vendor directory; it's just to keep your javascripts organized. For example: the `timeago.js` file for the timeago plugin is most likely minified and you probably won't be modifying it all. It should be in a different directory from the custom javascripts that you're actively working on.

Comment: Hey.. after moving the actual file to vendor/assets/stylesheets, how can we refer to it in the view page?? <link href="reportng.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />... Should I give relative path starting from root(public folder) to the stylesheet folder? or jus mention of filename is enough?

Comment: @akshatha you can just use the view helper: `stylesheet_link_tag :reporting`

Answer (score 1):

After looking for a solution to this problem for a while, I found this step by step tutorial which explain how to implement a bootstrap theme to a rails app => http://www.notch8.com/implementing-a-bootstrap-theme/

You can apply this to other CSS and JS templates than a Bootstrap one.

Hope this help (sorry if I make english mistakes)